# Show connection die, but still able to show the id on the url link

Tags: php

I'm new to the php programming and try to using the sql update query to update my inventories list, but someting gone wrong and show the error.

[image]

Dont have any idea why the url successfully shows the inventory ID but at the same time showing the "die". In here, the die referred to "connection die"

Below is the code I wrote for when user clicks edit button, it will go to "page-it-peripherals-update.php"

```
<form action="page-it-peripherals-update.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="edit-id" value="<?php echo $Iid ?>" />
<button name="edit" type="submit">Edit</button>
</form>
```

Below is the code I wrote try get the details of the selected inventory ID under the page called "page-it-peripherals-update.php"

```
  <?php
   if(isset($_POST['edit']))
     {
      $Iid = $_POST['edit-id'];
      $url = "http://localhost/inventory/page-it-peripherals-update.php?id=".$Iid;
      header("Location: {$url}");
     }else{
      echo 'die';
     }
 ?>
```

The problem is am I successfully get the inforamtion of the item details and how come it is also showing the else "die" at the same time?

Comment: You submit your form, `isset($_POST['edit'])` is true, so you redirect to  `page-it-peripherals-update.php?id=...`. So this script executes again, but now `isset($_POST['edit'])` won't be set any more (since the browser followed your redirect by making a new request using method GET), so it goes into the else branch now.

Comment: @CBroe, so I just need to remove the else function?

Comment: If you remove the else block, then this script won't do anything any more, when you call it via `page-it-peripherals-update.php?id=...`- which would then beg the question, why you would want to redirect to this URL in the first place then.

Comment: @CBroe, the reason I redirect to this URL is when the user click the edit button, then it jump to the page-it-peripherals-update page and get the id, but I managed to solve the problem already. :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

---- CODE EXPLAIN ----

At the first click on the button edit on the first page `home`   or index whatever

You are redirection to the page `page-it-peripherals-update.php`

Now at the page your `$_POST` should containt something like that

```
$_POST = {
    'edit-id' : 'some_val_here',
    'edit'    : true
}
```

the script from  `page-it-peripherals-update.php`

```
  <?php
   if(isset($_POST['edit'])) // <-- ho i my $_POST['edit'] is define
     {
      $Iid = $_POST['edit-id']; 
      $url = "http://localhost/inventory/page-it-peripherals-update.php?id=".$Iid; // make new url
      header("Location: {$url}"); // script : ho , let me relocation to the new page 
     }else{
      echo 'die';
     }
 ?>
```

And you call `page-it-peripherals-update.php` without any values define

Now at the page your `$_POST` should containt something like that

```
$_POST = { }
```

script :

```
  <?php
   if(isset($_POST['edit'])) // <-- ho i my $_POST['edit'] isn't define !
     {
      $Iid = $_POST['edit-id']; 
      $url = "http://localhost/inventory/page-it-peripherals-update.php?id=".$Iid; // make new url
      header("Location: {$url}");
     }else{
      echo 'die'; // print 'die'
     }
 ?>
```

---- comment ----

It dependat what resultat you want if u wont get redirected you should remove the `header("Location: {$url}");`

Or you can add on extra condition `isset($_REQUEST['edit-id'])` for if `edit-id`  is define at the url or not

Comment: Thank you. I manage to solve the problem. :)